# AvCapture error after upgrading Xcode 8 to XCode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, camera, avcapturesession

I am working on a code from another developer, it is a camera app. I worked on it and it was working fine before I upgraded to xCode 9. Below is the code snippet

```
@objc protocol AVCapturePhotoOutputType {
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
var isLensStabilizationDuringBracketedCaptureSupported: Bool {get}
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
var availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes: [Int] {get}
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
var isHighResolutionCaptureEnabled: Bool {get 
@objc(setHighResolutionCaptureEnabled:) set}
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
var supportedFlashModes: [Int] {get}
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func connection(withMediaType mediaType: String!) -> AVCaptureConnection!
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
@objc(capturePhotoWithSettings:delegate:)
func capturePhoto(with settings: AVCapturePhotoSettings, delegate: 
AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate)}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
extension AVCapturePhotoOutput:AVCapturePhotoOutputType {}
```

Now I am getting error on line extension AVCapturePhotoOutput:AVCapturePhotoOutputType {} i.e. extending protocol.This is the error

```
Type 'AVCapturePhotoOutput' does not conform to protocol 'AVCapturePhotoOutputType'
```

xCode is also providing option for auto fix, when I apply that two stubs are generated and I starts getting error as shown in pic below.

[image: Errors after adding stubs]

I did't understand why it happened after upgrading to xCode 9, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly same problem. Just replace your protocol with this protocol

```
@objc protocol AVCapturePhotoOutputType {
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
var isLensStabilizationDuringBracketedCaptureSupported: Bool {get}
//### `availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes` is temporarily renamed to `__availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes`,
//### Maybe more Swiftish refinement is planned, but not yet completed.
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
@objc(availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes)
var __availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes: [NSNumber] {get}
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
var isHighResolutionCaptureEnabled: Bool {get @objc(setHighResolutionCaptureEnabled:) set}
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
//### `supportedFlashModes` is temporarily renamed to `__supportedFlashModes`,
//### Maybe more Swiftish refinement is planned, but not yet completed.
@objc(supportedFlashModes)
var __supportedFlashModes: [NSNumber] {get}
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
@objc(connectionWithMediaType:)
func connection(with mediaType: AVMediaType) -> AVCaptureConnection?
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
@objc(capturePhotoWithSettings:delegate:)
func capturePhoto(with settings: AVCapturePhotoSettings, delegate: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate)
}
```

cheers :-)